# Stumped - indexOf is returning -1 on stored variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I've looked everywhere and all up and down this forum. Can someone help with this? Basically, indexOf is returning a -1 on a stored variable. I prob missed something simple but I can't seem to find it.

```
var t1 = {

    "properties" : [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "streetName" : "N. 10th", 
            "blockNo": "5800", 
            "addresses" : [5800, 5801, 5802, 5803, 5804, 5005], 
            "home": [5802]
        },
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "streetName" : "N. 10th", 
            "blockNo": "5900", 
            "addresses" : [5900, 5901, 5902, 5903, 5904, 5905],
            "home" : [5904, 5905]
        }
    ]
}


var myProp = t1.properties;

var list = myProp[0].addresses;

var atHome = myProp[0].home;

var homeIndex = list.indexOf(atHome);


document.write(homeIndex); //returns -1. Why is this when the others work? 
document.write(atHome); //returns 5802
document.write(list.indexOf(5802)); //returns 2, which is what I'm looking for.
```

JSFiddle is here - https://jsfiddle.net/qmn7h7pb/
Very simple but doesn't work when the vars are swapped. If you swap out the var

homeIndex = list.indexOf(5802), it returns 2(correct).
homeIndex = list.indexOf(atHome) returns -1. (incorrect)

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Because `document.write(atHome);` coerces the `atHome` array into string. You should do `var homeIndex = list.indexOf(atHome[0]);` in your code.

Comment: Thx but if I knew the index number then there's no need for the indexOf() function. However, found the answer below. I feel like this is a simple fix but very important. Thx for your help.

Comment: If you go with `document.write` or `alert` or something for logging instead of `console.log`, you should *always* enclose the value in `JSON.stringify(…)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually `myProp[0].home` returns String and in your array all elements are integer, So you need to convert in int then check, change here

```
var atHome = parseInt (myProp[0].home);
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/qmn7h7pb/1/

Comment: Thanks man that's AWESOME! I know it's simple but I would have never had figured that nuance out. U the man. I'd thumbs up you if I could

Answer (score 0):

You must loop over atHome array to get its elements:

```
var myProp = t1.properties;

var list = myProp[0].addresses;

 var atHome = myProp[0].home;
 for(var i = 0 ; i < atHome.length; i += 1) {
 var homeIndex = list.indexOf(atHome[i]);
  alert(homeIndex);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1L9e4bxr/